# Barcode is not generating properly in zebra designer

Tags: zebra-printers, zebra-scanners

I am creating barcode in zebra designer for 15 digits.
But in the printing the barcode in generating for 14 digits.
It is ignoring the last digit.
I had scanned through mobile app and also in zebra barcode scanner gun.

- I need to generate barcode for this value - `448502006000035`
- barcode creating for this digits - `44850200600003`

we are using Code128

Answer (score 0):

```
^XA 
^BQ,2,17
^FD>;448502006000035^FS
^XZ
```

you can use this [Code viewer online](http://labelary.com/viewer.html) to preview.